# SharePoint 2010 Search Not Working: Tried Everything!

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

1. I've made sure the Foundation Service and Search related services are turned on
2. I've made sure the file type is valid
3. I've made sure Crawl is configured
4. Select Microsoft SharePoint Foundation search server (I've specified this on each content database)
5. The CRAWL is showing as successful

I'm at the end of my tether, I really can't figure this out? Internal Server Error exception keeps popping up when a srarch is made.

Comment: Have you checked the event viewer for erros on the sharepoint server evrytime you do a search?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any Term Stored?  Have you configured the Search Scopes??  Have you tried using [FAST Search Tool](http://fastforsharepoint.codeplex.com/) to verify it's not the problem from SharePoint side??

Comment: Yes and yes. Absolutely no problem from the sharepoint side. No errors are even showing on the Crawl

Comment: does the content access account have permissions to crawl the site?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Administrator account